# States could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working through a course called *Learn to Code by Making Games*. I am in the process of creating a text adventure game.

My questions are why I am getting this error message and how do I prevent this from happening in the future:

"The type or namespace name 'States' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference).

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;


public class TextController : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text text;
private enum Location { Cell, Hallway_Beginning, Front_of_Chute_Room, 
Empty_Chute_Room, Friends_in_high_places, You_Win };
private States myState;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    print(myState);
    if (myState == States.Cell)
    {
        state_Cell();
    }
 }

void state_Cell() {
    text.text = "text";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        myState = States.Cell;
    }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and answer my question!

Comment: You don't have a `Enum` type of `State` as far as I can see based on your provided code. I believe it should be `Location` instead

Comment: The message is clear: the compiler cannot find `States`.  Neither can we, its not there.  Did you mean `Location` - it has a  `Cell` at least.